# PHP, if A then B and C else D and E

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

How do I properly write a conditional statement where if A is true, then do B AND C, else do D and E.

```
if (empty($A)) { B=0 AND C=0; }
  else {D=X AND E=Y; }
```

in general, does that look right?

Here's my actual code:

```
if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
$filelink = '' AND $filetext = '';
} else {
$filelink = mysql_real_escape_string($location) AND
$filetext = 'Open File';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the braces are for; they create a block. Whatever is in that block will execute. You can put as many statements as you want within the same block:

```
if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $filelink = '';
    $filetext = '';
} else {
    $filelink = mysql_real_escape_string($location);
    $filetext = 'Open File';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @joseph-silber (or @samuel-cook).  Can you explain more why AND can't be used here?  Just for my education, if you have a moment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $filelink = '';
    $filetext = '';
} else {
    $filelink = mysql_real_escape_string($location);
    $filetext = 'Open File';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `AND` between the statements

```
if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $filelink = '';
    $filetext = '';
} else {
    $filelink = mysql_real_escape_string($location)l
    $filetext = 'Open File';
}
```

If the `if` statement evaluates to true, all the code between the next matching curly braces will be run. If false, all the code between the matching curly braces after else will be run.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation, @jonathan-kuhn.  As you can tell, I'm new to PHP and this helps me understand more than just the language.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

AND is an operator.

It is a logical operator and takes two operands. Left and Right or L+R.

It first evaluates the left hand operand L and then converts it to bool. If the value is false then R never executes and the operator returns false. It if is true then R is evaluated and converted to bool. If the bool is true then the operator returns true otherwise false.

So from what you are saying you want to execute the statement using the AND operator to achieve a temporary boolean value that will never get used.

Your logic is faulty from that perspective. Rather use a ";" token to separate the statement. Instead of saying (A AND B) say {A;B;} and then A and B will both just be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand a bit more here, @bobshacks.